# How to get a table to show only the active month and previous month?

Tags: powerbi, dashboard

I have a table with the columns |Month|Year|Cost|. I want my table visual to show the current month and previous month only, how do I go about automating this so I don't have to click the specific month on the filter?

Answer (score 0):

Select your Visual. Go to Filter and select the Date column. Fill in according image below and Apply Filter.

[image]

Comment: Aldert, I found out what my issue is. The field that I have month_year is not formated as a month. I tried to create a new column called date, however i am having issues. The original field that I made date month shows the cost for just that specific month. What I am seeing now is several entries

Comment: So do you know what to do or do you need help?